# How to get text orientation in PDFDocument?

Tags: php, text, orientation, pdflib

i am using PdfLib in PHP. 
I need to get text orientation in pdf-document? 
How do i can do this?
Maybe i can get text position and find out angle rotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these function for single line of text:

```
$p->fit_textline("The famous rocket looper", 300, 500, "orientate=south");
$p->fit_textline("The famous rocket looper", 50, 350, "rotate=30");
```

possible orientations: north, south, east, west

If you use TextFlows you can use this function:

```
$p->fit_textflow($tf, 250, 50, 400, 400, "rotate=30"); // and 'orientate' should work as well
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to get text orientation in existing document. I need  to get text orientation in user uploaded document and if orintation is wrong(unreadable) then change document orientation.

Comment: Maybe someone has an idea how to do it differently?